# SQL Nested Case When with numeric check

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, numeric

I'm trying to create a "filter" with SQL.

I have a table named ARTICLE like this :

```
    CODE           |  NAME           |  QUANTITY    |
    _______________|_________________|_______________   
    0020717270084  |  MANGO FRUIT 1L |      3       |
    0884394000774  |  ALOE VERA 50CL |      4       |
    16             |  CHEWING GUM    |      10      |
    IGLOO          |  IGLOO ICE      |      5       |
```

I want to do a SELECT with a verification on CODE.
If CODE is a number AND has a length of 8 OR 10 OR 13 digits, i display CODE ELSE i have to display `*` before CODE (simple concat).

I can do CASE WHEN but this one is a little bit tricky for me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do this with a `case` statement.  Databases do the checks differently.  The following is an approach using SQL Server:

```
select (case when len(code) in (8, 10, 13) and code not like '%[^0-9]%'
             then code
             else '*' + code
        end)
```

Comment: i have tried the `not like` one but it didn't work, btw, your select works perfectly ! thanks a lot